# how to grep between two lines in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have got 1 file which looks like this

```
COMPANY=xyz
system.employee[0].Name=shayam
system.employee[0].Age=26
system.employee[0].sex=Male
system.employee[1].Name=ram
system.employee[1].Age=28
system.employee[1].sex=Male

COMPANY=bhg
system.employee[0].Location=Bangalore
system.employee[0].Number=26
system.employee[1].Location=chennai
system.employee[1].Number=28
```

I want to form a table with company xyz with columns Name , Age, sex and one more table with columns Location & Number. 
Can you help me how to acheive this using perl The output should be like this

```
COMPANY xyz 

Name     Age    Sex

Shayam   26     Male

Ram      28     Male


COMPANY bgh

Location     Number

Bangalore      26

Chennai        28
```

Thanks

Comment: If i grep the lines between "COMPANY= ", I can acheive this. how to grep the lines between two keywords in grep?

Comment: Can you add the sample output you required?

Comment: ouput should be a table like                                          COMPANY=xyz                                                           Name      Age      sex                                            shayam    26         Male   
Ram       28         Male                                           

COMPANY=bhg                                                         Location     Number                                                Bangalore    26                                                     Chennai      28


Thanks

Comment: I am unable to set the view here. Table name should be company=xyz and the columns are Name Age sex under which the entries should be present. and one more table with name company=bhg and columns for that table are Location and Number.

Comment: edit your question and add the required format.

Comment: Hi space. Please see the format of the output in the squestion

Comment: Tell us what you tried / what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rough code below does a progressive match i.e. it moves down the string to extract the data you want. Similar code could be used for the second part of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inline;
{
    local $/ = undef;    #turn on slurp mode
    $inline = <DATA>;
}

print "COMPANY xyz\nName Age sex\n";    #Report header

$inline =~ s/^COMPANY=xyz\n(.*)COMPANY=bhg/$1/msx;    #strip off surplus text to
$inline =~ s/system\.employee\[\d+\]\.//gx;    #simplify progressive match below

while (
    $inline =~ /
(?:                 #start of non capturing block
    Name=(.*)\n
    Age=(.*)\n
    sex=(.*)\n
){1}            # end of non-capturing block (progressive match)
/gmx    # g=progressive match, m=multiline match x=comments
  )
{
    print "$1 $2 $3\n";
}

__DATA__
COMPANY=xyz
system.employee[0].Name=shayam
system.employee[0].Age=26
system.employee[0].sex=Male
system.employee[1].Name=ram
system.employee[1].Age=28
system.employee[1].sex=Male

COMPANY=bhg
system.employee[0].Location=Bangalore
system.employee[0].Number=26
system.employee[1].Location=chennai
system.employee[1].Number=28
```